# struct-member variable not chaning

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm not quite sure who i should this, the arduino-folks of the c++-folks, so i ask you both.

I'm trying to make a little library for Arduino. I have a problem where i cannot get a member variable of a struct to change. I'll just show the code and the tell what goes wrong.

ButtonGroup.h:

```
#ifndef BUTTONGROUP_H
#define BUTTONGROUP_H

#include "Arduino.h"

struct button {
    int buttonState;
    int lastButtonState;
    int pin;
    void (*f)(int);
};

class ButtonGroup {
public:
    ButtonGroup(int dimension);
    ~ButtonGroup();
    virtual void addButton(int pin, void (*f)(int));
    virtual void loopButtons();

private:
    button* buttons;
    int count;
};
#endif
```

ButtonGroup.cpp:

```
#include "ButtonGroup.h"

ButtonGroup::ButtonGroup(int dimension) {

    buttons = new button[dimension];
    count = 0;
}

 ButtonGroup::~ButtonGroup() {

     delete [] buttons;

}

 void ButtonGroup::addButton(int pin, void (*f)(int)){
    button b = {0, 0, pin, f};
    buttons[count] = b;
    pinMode(pin, INPUT);
    count++;
}

void ButtonGroup::loopButtons(){
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        button b = buttons[i];

        b.buttonState = digitalRead(b.pin);

        if (b.buttonState == 0 && b.lastButtonState == 1) {
            (b.f(2));
        }

        b.lastButtonState = b.buttonState;
    }
}
```

I try to detect when my button hits a falling edge (prevoius button state is 1 and current is 0), and then i want to call the member function. My problem is that when i try to change the lastButtonState in the last line, the value has not changed the next time i call loopButtons(). It seems like I'm working on a local copy or something, but since i'm accessing an array I thought it should be fine? I suspect it has something with pointer/reference/value to do, but i can't figure out how to work around it.

I run and compile the code through the Arduino IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing this `button b = buttons[i];` to this `button& b = buttons[i];` (and yes, you were using a local copy, just like you were in `addButton` right before you copied it into the array with the assignment statement, but this time in reverse).

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot!! Can you perhaps describe what went wrong? I'm pretty new to c++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you did in `addButton`

```
button b = {0, 0, pin, f}; // Local Object
buttons[count] = b;        // copied to array via assignment
```

So was your handler, but in reverse:

```
button b = buttons[i]; // Local object copy-constructed from array element

b.buttonState = digitalRead(b.pin); // remaining code working on local copy.
```

By using a reference, no copy is made and we reference the array item via the reference variable:

```
button& b = buttons[i]; // using reference to buttons[i]

b.buttonState = digitalRead(b.pin); // remaining code modifying buttons[i] using b
```

Answer (score 1):

In the function ButtonGroup::loopButtons(), you declare 


`button b = buttons[i];`

At this point you are creating a variable b, of type button.  When you apply assignemnent (=buttons[i]), you are taking the *new* button b and giving it the value of the button stored at buttons[i] (i.e. you are copying the button).

You could solve this by changing the line to 

`button& b = buttons[i];`

This will create a reference to the button stored at buttons[i], which has the desired effect.

If you don't mind a couple style pointsers:  b is a bad variable name, and you should prefer using a c++ array or vector rather than a c style array.